# How to convert a JSON object string to a Javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, stringify

I passed back a JSON object from a service and converted it to a string using `JSON.stringify` but the required output is not as expected as shown in the first example below:

What it **looks like** after stringify call on the JSON object:

`[{"RID":"98798","appName":"TestApp"},{"RID":"98799","appName":"TestApp Two"}]`

What it **needs** to look like:

`["98798 TestApp","98799 TestApp Two"];`

*How can I convert a JSON object to a presentable javascript array?*

What I've tried -

- I tried calling first stringify which doesn't give the required format as shown above:

  `var ridAppList = JSON.stringify(dataRID);`
- I also attempted converting that stringified string to a JS array using parseJSON but I get a result like - `[object Obect], [object Object]`:

  `var ridAppList = $.parseJSON('[' + ridAppList + ']');`

This is the complete assignment for context. Inside the success function of an Ajax GET call a JSON object is returned

```
           success: function (result) {
                var dataRID;
                dataRID = result;
                ridAppList = JSON.stringify(dataRID);
                alert(ridAppList);

            },
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the array and build a new one with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var array = [{ "RID": "98798", "appName": "TestApp" }, { "RID": "98799", "appName": "TestApp Two" }],
    result = array.map(function (a) {
        return a.RID + ' ' + a.appName;
    });
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers here are valid for your example, but here's a solution for arbitrary property quantity and names.

```js
var flatObjects = [
        {"RID":"98798","appName":"TestApp"},
        {"RID":"98799","appName":"TestApp Two"},
        {"ABB":"98799","appMode":"Test", "feature": 2}
    ].map(function (obj) {
        var values = Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { 
         return obj[key]
        })
        return values.join(' ')
    })

var result = JSON.stringify(flatObjects)
console.log(result)
```

Edit: Code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

After you [**parsed**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)  `JSON` you can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like this

```js
var string = [{"RID":"98798","appName":"TestApp"},{"RID":"98799","appName":"TestApp Two"}];

var result = string.map(function(e) {
  return e.RID += ' ' + e.appName;
});

console.log(result)
```

Or with ES6 you can just do this

```js
var string = [{"RID":"98798","appName":"TestApp"},{"RID":"98799","appName":"TestApp Two"}];

var result = string.map(e => e.RID += ' ' + e.appName);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer also uses [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) but combines ES6 [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), and [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for an especially concise procedure.

```js
var input = [
  {"RID":"98798","appName":"TestApp"},
  {"RID":"98799","appName":"TestApp Two"}
];

var output = input.map(({RID, appName})=> `${RID} ${appName}`);

console.log(output);

// [
//   "98798 TestApp",
//   "98799 TestApp Two"
// ]
```